# How to open private class in WindowBuilder Pro?

Tags: windowbuilder

I develop JFace Wizard dialog. [WindowBuilder](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/) allow to edit [wizard pages](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/wizard/WizardPage.html), but i don't want to put my pages into separate files. How to instruct WindowBuilder parser to allow edit private class ? I've tried `@wbp.parser.preferredRoot` and `@wbp.parser.entryPoint` tags as below, but doesn't work.

```
public class ResetPasswordDialog extends Wizard {
    ...

    @Override
    public void addPages() {
        Page1 p = new Page1(); // @wbp.parser.preferredRoot
        addPage(p);
        addPage(new Page2());
        addPage(new Page3());
    }

}

class Page1 extends WizardPage {
   /**
    * @wbp.parser.entryPoint
    */
   @Override
   public void createControl(Composite parent) {
       ...
   }
}

class Page2 extends WizardPage {
}

class Page3 extends WizardPage {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WindowBuilder will not work with private components or inner classes. This is intentional and will not be changed. If you want to use WindowBuilder, each class must be extracted to a separate file.